# How to solve the given differential equation using power series method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, power-series

The given differential equation is $\frac{df(r)}{dr}=\frac{f(2r)}{2f(r)}$. How do I solve this differential equation using power series method?

I know the answers. They are $\sin(r)$, $r$ and $\sinh(r)$. The problem is, how do I show that the solutions are these.

Comment: Since you have $f(2r)$ this is not really considered a "pure" differential equation.

Comment: So, how do I solve it?

Comment: $f(r)=e^{r}/2$ is a solution

Comment: I know the answers. They are $\sin(r)$, $r$ and $\sinh(r)$. The problem is, how do I show that the solutions are these.

Comment: $f (r)=r $ is a solution.

Comment: You can just plug them into the equation. For example the solution $r$ gives $\frac{dr}{dr}=\frac{2r}{2r}$ which you can see is true.

Comment: But how do you know that there is no more solutions?

Comment: @Χpẘ I see it but I want to solve it analytically using power series method.

Comment: @DebobrataRajak you should add that info to the OP.

Comment: @Basti This is the link I am referring to [link](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept03/Trodden/Trodden2.html) . It says on solving using power series method one gets the solutions as mentioned above. But I am not getting the solutions as desired.

Comment: So, please: 1) update your question so that it includes all relevant information and 2) show some effort. What have you tried, and why don't you get it to work? Where do you get stuck? &c

Comment: Apparently the conclusion at the link is wrong. Because, as Basti said, $f(r)=e^r/2$ is a solution, unless the additional condition $f (r) \approx r$ as $r \rightarrow 0$ eliminates that solution, in which case you need to update the OP to include this condition.